# from which version graphql api is supported in github

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I am trying to access graphql API in my local github version enterprise 2.7, but its giving error 404 page not found.

Here is url of graphql
https://10.13.28.120/api/v4

So just want to check from which version graphql is supported in github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this release note](https://enterprise.github.com/releases/2.10.0/notes) (June 2017), GraphQL API is available from Github enterprise 2.10.0. It isn't available on Github Enterprise 2.7 (and won't likely be implemented as the same release note announce v2.7 deprecation in August 2017)

From [Github Enterprise 2.10 documentation](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.10/v4/guides/forming-calls/#the-graphql-endpoint), it can be accessed from this endpoint :

```
http(s)://[hostname]/api/graphql
```